# build object hierarchy using observables

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a object that represents a large community and all of its subcommunities. It essentially is a hiarchy of main community with multiple nested communities that have one or more nested communities themselves.

There is a factor of recursion to take into consideration, this is how the data structure should look like at the end:

```
{
  id: "1",
  name: "Car Club",
  communities: [
    {
      id: "11",
      name: "Euro Group",
      communities: [
        {
          id: "111",
          name: "Ferrari Club"
        }, {
          id: "112",
          name: "Audi Club"
        }

      ]
    },
    {
      id: "12",
      name: "Asian Fan Club",
      communities: [
        {
          id: "121",
          name: "Japanese Club",
          communities: [
            {
              id: "1211",
              name: "Toyota Group"
            }, {
              id: "1212",
              name: "Suzuki Group"
            }
          ]
        }, {
          id: "122",
          name: "Great Wall Group"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is as far as i got before my brain blew up.

```
export class Community {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  communities: Community[]; // think of it sub communities
}

getCommunityById(id: string){
   this.communityService.getById(id) // this calls the remote server for data
   .subscribe((res: any) => {
        var community = new Community();
        community.id = res.id
        community.name = res.name;
        if (community.communities?.length) {
          community.communities = [];

          community.communities.forEach((e: any) => {
            var community = getCommunityById(e.id);
            community.communities.push(community);
          });
    }
  });
}
```

I know the above is incorrect, but here we are.

Appreciate helping me untangle the spaghetti code above.

Comment: if you want to do it that way, you need to call a recursive function.
but do you really need `new Community()` ?  does the Community class do other stuff you can you use a simple `interface` ?

Comment: @Zerotwelve sure can be interface, eventually will have internal functions to consume

Answer (score 1):

So, if you only need an interface, you don't need to transform it into a class, the `res` already has the correct structure and you could call some static functions instead (where you pass the community interface as input).

but if you really really need a class, then this I think should work:

```js
.subscribe((jsonCommunities: any) => {
    const newCommunity = new Community();
    newCommunity.id = jsonCommunities.id
    newCommunity.name = jsonCommunities.name;
    if (jsonCommunities.communities?.length) {
        newCommunity.communities = [];
        this.recursiveCommunity(jsonCommunities.communities, newCommunity);
    }
    console.log('Complete community tree: ', newCommunity)
});


recursiveCommunity(){jsonCommunities: any[], classCommunity:Community}{
    for(jsonCommunity of jsonCommunities){
        const newCommunity = new Community();
        newCommunity.id = jsonCommunity.id
        newCommunity.name = jsonCommunity.name;
        if (jsonCommunity.communities?.length) {
            newCommunity.communities = [];
            this.recursiveCommunity(jsonCommunity.communities, newCommunity);
        }
        classCommunity.communities.push(newCommunity);
    }

}
```

Comment: So where is the bit that calls the server to get the data and populate the community? That is the challenge, you need to call each sub community to be able to create the object. You don't know how many nested communities there are so you have to keep polling the server till you get the final one

Comment: well I assumed that wenn you call the API you will get the JSON as represented in your question with all the sub-communities.
You could do recursive GET requests but that would be very inefficient and complicated. You should edit the backend so that you receive a complete JSON

Comment: not for my use case, I avoid bulk calls. Instead I make data async so as it loads the child communities it displays them to the user. One of the future options will be to control depth manually

Comment: so what exactly is the response when you call `this.communityService.getById(id)` ?

Comment: returns a community object from server containing ID, NAME, and COMMUNITIES.